# For loop prints immediately console.log() for all cycles while rest of loop still runs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, asynchronous

I am pretty new to Selenium and Nodejs, so please don't judge too hard on me. I am trying to figure out, why `console.log()` seems to be asynchronous(?) within my `for` loop?!

Why does my testing `for` loop prints immediately all console.log() lines to the console, while the overall function is still running? I do not get it. I thought node would need to be told by `setTimeout()` to do asynchronous work?

My code snippet:

```
function cycleClicks(j) {
    for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        tabStrategyTester.click();
        driver.sleep(1000);
        if (tabStrategyTester.isDisplayed()) {
            console.log("angezeigt");
        }
        else {
            console.log("nicht angezeigt");
        }
    }
}
cycleClicks(10);
```

The console displays me 10x "angezeigt" even if the browser did not even start up until then. So the `isDisplayed()` function returns `true` while  the browser is not even up. Additionally the `for` loop is not working synchronous, as I understand it.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the driver is only a wrapper - telling it to `sleep` will mean that the *driver* will wait before executing whatever else is in its queue, but that's *completely separate* from the Javascript thread. If you want your `console.log`s to appear 1 second apart, you should use Promises and `await` instead (which is Javascript-based asynchronousness, rather than Selenium-based asynchronous):

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function cycleClicks(j) {
  for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    tabStrategyTester.click();
    await sleep(1000);
    if (tabStrategyTester.isDisplayed()) {
      console.log("angezeigt");
    }
    else {
      console.log("nicht angezeigt");
    }
  }
}
cycleClicks(10);
```

But it would still be better to keep the asynchronousness confined to the driver side of things, when possible.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Now what it does is: it instantenously starts that looped console.log() outpout without the browser being started. So the console.log() output is timed with 1000ms but it is not reacting on what I want to be the signal: check if there is a certain element displayed on the website, which selenium-webdriver should check. Nevertheless thank you so far. Maybe some other hint here, on how I can let node wait until selenium-webdriver actually did its tasks (here starting browser and get a certain website)?